# how to test MFMailComposeViewController in simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a way to test sending emails from `MFMailComposeViewController` in iphone simulator ?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't test it on simulator...(I mean your mail won't be delivered).we will be able to test limited things like: how the view will be,what happens when the user clicks on cancel button etc...

To test whether, the mail was delivered or not, you have to use a Device. The device should be configured with some mail(ex:gmail) in your settings.

Answer (score 1):

Actual mail sending is not possible from the simulator.
Install the APP on a phone to test that.

However you can test everything that your APP can do/control/specify in the simulator.
Everything after the pressing of the Send button is Apple, so you can assume that is
working okay.

Answer (score -6):

Read [`Sending mail with MFMailComposeViewController`](http://blog.veladan.org/post/45417944228/sending-mail-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

First include MessageUI framework an implement MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
}
```

then implement a method like this one an the delegate method for removing the mail controller.

```
- (IBAction)pressentMailController:(id)sender {

    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Test subject!"];

    // Set up the recipients.
    /*NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first@example.com",
                             nil];
    NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",
                             @"third@example.com", nil];
    NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",
                              nil];

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
    [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];
    */

    // Attach an image to the email.
    /*NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ipodnano"
                                                     ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png"
                     fileName:@"ipodnano"];
    */
    // Fill out the email body text.
    NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining in sunny California!";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    // Present the mail composition interface.
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release]; // Can safely release the controller now.
}

// The mail compose view controller delegate method
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The code allows to add recipients, body, subject and attachements. Uncomment the lines as needed.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, you understood my question differently, I meant : how to test whether the MFMailComposeViewController really sent the email or not after pressing the send button !!? because when I checked out my email, I could not find any email sent from that composer (using simulator)  I'm sorry for confusing words..

Comment: -1 answering the wrong question.  The question was how to test the mail controller in the simulator.  The answer shows how to write the code but does not allow testing because the mail controller does not work in the simulator.