# How to use MFMailComposeViewController with simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, swift2, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to use a MFMailComposeViewController() in Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.0.1. I fear, this is a duplicate question, but didn't find a solution.

My code:

```
@IBAction func sendMail(sender: AnyObject) {
  let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
  picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
  picker.setSubject(subject.text!)
  picker.setMessageBody(body.text, isHTML: true)
  presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
   switch result.rawValue {
   case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
       print("Mail cancelled")
   case MFMailComposeResultSaved.rawValue:
       print("Mail saved")
  case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
       print("Mail sent")
  case MFMailComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
       print("Mail sent failure: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
  default:
      break
 }
 dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

The error is thrown in
     print("Mail cancelled")

When I test this on my device (iPad) everything is fine. But when i use the simulator, i get the error

```
 viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error          
 Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" 
 UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
 Mail cancelled
```

But I want to run this in simulator to see, how it looks i.e. on iPhone 6...

Comment: Do you have an email account setup on the simulator?

Comment: @Fogmeister: upps: how can i do this?

Comment: Same as on your iPhone. Just go into settings on the simulator and set up the email as normal.

Comment: ok, think that i'm crazy, but can't find it in settings... :-(

Comment: Try opening mail on the simulator. I don't have my computer tam so I can check it. But it's in the settings on the actual simulator. Use it like your phone. Not the normal Mac preferences.

Comment: in my settings i have the choice between "General", "Privacy", "iCloud" and so on. I found nothing in this points. On my device i use "iCloud" but in simulator this is a Dummy...

Comment: hang on. Just starting simulator now. Will try it myself.

Comment: When I sign into the simulator with iCloud I get an option to enable email.

Comment: ii´ll try it again...

Comment: Hmm... But it seems I can't send anything with the email action. Even in the photos app the mail compose sheet just opens and closes instantly.

Comment: Just seen this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439932/how-to-test-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-simulator

Comment: i don't know why, but this time i got an access to iCloud.com and is was accepted! Now evereything is fine. :-) Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: ... but i get the same error when sending the mail: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

Comment: See the link. You can't do it from be simulator. I had assumed that you had googled it or searched stack overflow before posting.

Comment: ok, perhaps it'l run on a future version of Xcode :-( Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You have to first check if the device can send mail with `MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()`

```
@IBAction func sendMail(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
        else { 
            // TODO: Alert the user its device cannot send mail
            print("Mail services are not available")
            return 
    } 

    let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
    picker.setSubject(subject.text!)
    picker.setMessageBody(body.text, isHTML: true)
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```